# Windows batch programming - conflict handling

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, automation, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins

I want to upload a patch to Jenkins but if there is a conflict so the run will abort.

I tried using this code:

```
REM SETUP: Apply the patch if there is one
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" patch %WORKSPACE%\%UPLOADED_PATCH_FILE%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR_HANDLER

echo.
echo PATCH UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY!!
GOTO QUIT

:ERROR_HANDLER
echo.
echo ERROR occurred while uploading the patch!!!
exit 1

:QUIT
REM SETUP: Delete the patch file
cd %WORKSPACE%
del /Q /F %UPLOADED_PATCH_FILE%
```

But the conflict don't throw any error just this message:

```
00:00:01.738 Summary of conflicts:
00:00:01.738   Skipped paths: 1
```

Anyone have an idea how to catch this message?

Thanks!

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: What exactly contain variable %SVN_STATUS% ??

Comment: Nothing.. it is leftover I forgot to delete

Comment: Well you were not showing us all of your batch file which affected some of this code. Not sure how we are supposed to troubleshoot when you do not show us what is creating two variables that you are not showing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for it:

```
REM SETUP: Apply the patch if there is one
@echo off
set pattern=Summary of conflicts:

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" patch %WORKSPACE%\%UPLOADED_PATCH_FILE%`) DO (
 if "%pattern%"=="%%F" (
        @echo on
        ECHO "***************************************************************************"
        ECHO "***************************************************************************"
        ECHO "*********ERROR: Conflict found in the patch. Try try again......***********"
        ECHO "***************************************************************************"
        ECHO "***************************************************************************"
        EXIT 1
        )

)

@echo on
```